# Execution failed for task ':react-native-background-timer:processReleaseResources'

Tags: android, linux, reactjs, react-native, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed fresh Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

My echo `$JAVA_HOME` returns `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`

- Installed node,
- cloned from git and setting up react-native project,
- have emulator and its working.

Installed npm in project directory and started npm in project directory then whenever I run react-native run-android. I face this error below:

```
:react-native-background-timer:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-background-timer:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Following line is also added in `project/android/app/build.grade`

```
compile project(':react-native-background-timer')
```

Please help me in setting up react-native project. I am complete novice in react-native.

Comment: Having the same issue, any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately no luck yet.